# Как перезаписать файл?

Tags: android, kotlin

Сохраняю файл следующим кодом:

```
val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "docs.json")
}
val destinationUri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
destinationUri?.let { uri ->
    contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri, "rwt")?.use { outputStream ->
        outputStream.write(json.toByteArray())
        outputStream.close()
   }
}
```

Каждый раз при выполнении кода создается новый файл с циферкой в названии. Как перезаписать уже имеющийся файл docs.json?

Comment: Очевидно что не нужно вызывать `insert`, а вместо этого найти Uri уже существующего, дальше одинаково.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Спасибо! Получилось проверить наличие uri через запрос к контент резольверу и уже его подставлять в поток.